# showing swf files in android 4.4.4

Tags: android, flash

i'm using webview for this but i can't load swf in android kitkat v4.4.4
my code is working well in android 4.4.3 and earlier versions of android but in v4.4.4 it's not working.
what should i do?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;


public class MyGameActivity extends Activity {

    WebView mWebView;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/game.swf");
    }
}
```

Comment: flash player is by default not installed in android 4.4.4

Comment: i have installed last version of flash player on my phone

Answer (score 0):

SWF no longer supported on Android Webkit. They might re-support it in newer versions